# REGEX - Find first word of a string of text

Tags: regex

i'm looking for a regex to pick the fist word of a textbox in a game.

Example:

```
James
Hello my friend, how are you?
```

I would like to know a regex that picks "JAMES" from that example.
So it has to pick the first word, and only if there is a linebreak after it.

How would you recommend me to do it?

I already tried `^.+:` but it only works whenever the name has a colon at the end (James:)

Comment: Stop tag spamming. You're not possibly using several regex libraries at the same time. Please use only tags that actually apply to your question, and remove the ones that do not.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this REGEXP would help you

(.*[\n\t])

You can test it on this web page https://regexr.com/. It always helps me to verify my regular expressions. Also the next web page it's a valuable resource

https://regexlib.com/

Comment: Thanks! This one worked for me!
The others did do work, but didn't ingame, this one actually did!

Answer (score -1):

The following Regex may work for you

`^(\w+)\s?.*\n`

[You can demonstrate the regex here:](https://regex101.com/r/DuQlMD/1)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
/^\w+$\n/gm
```

Review it at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bM23qQ/1)

```
^    /* beginning of line */
\w+  /* one or more word characters = [A-Za-z0-9]
$    /* end of line */
\n   /* new line */
/gm  /* 'g'lobal flag for multiple matches and 'm'ultiline flag to 
        designate the start ^ and end $ of a line */
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use the "word boundary" `\b`

Something like that `/^(.+)\b/`

This should

- `^` => the pattern must start with
- `( )` => capture
- `.+` => anything
- `\b` => end of a word

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/i7iU0r)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `/^\w+$\n/gm` if you are looking for a word that only ends with `newline` as

[DEMO](https://regexr.com/6i7gu)

[image]

If you are looking for a regex that has only one word then you can use `^\w+$`

[DEMO](https://regexr.com/6i7h1)

[image]